# Web3 is not defined - Require not found

Tags: web3js

I am trying to connect and interact with a local blockchain (using ganache-cli) through the web3js library. I have created a local website that uses web3js library but I keep getting the following error message in my browser console when I try to load the web page.

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined

web3.min.js:1:636

    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js:1

ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined
```

I am using the following code

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a [bug report](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3074) already filed for this.  It will be fixed in version `1.2.2` (current version is `1.2.1`).

Assuming this ever worked, you can try using a prior version

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.2.1/dist/web3.min.js"></script>`

where you replace `1.2.1` with the version that didn't have this issue.

Comment: thank you for the answer. now the error goes away when using 1.2.0 but when trying to access the account addresses, the return is null. any idea why is that happening.

Comment: better to open as a separate question, as depending on how you do it, it could be a different issue.  Most commonly I see people forget to use `await` when calling web3 functions like `getAccounts`.

Comment: this is a new requirement as i have read to call the await, correct?